# Create division among dynamically created div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

I made a personal project where I can enter movie title(s) in a search bar and get information about them. The data is in json which uses api from omdb. Here's the main part of code:

```
//film[] is an array of strings contains movie titles

//this array works perfectly giving me 0 through lenght-1 elements
for(var i= 0; i< film.length; i++)
    console.log(i+" : "+film[i]);
console.log("Film you entered is "+ film);

//#load is section element that is use to display "loading" while the data is recieved
$('#load').html("<h2>LOadiNG.....................</h2>"); 

//looping for each movie
for(var j= 0; j< film.length; j++){
    $.getJSON("http://www.omdbapi.com/?t="+film[j]+"&y=&plot=short&r=json", function(json) {

        //does not work if I give 3 titles, shows "processing 3 : undefined" all the time
        console.log("processing "+j+" : "+film[j]);

        /*
         *#info is section element where the data is displayed
         *".for-info" styles each div child inside section so that each movie has a visible seperation
         *(this is what I want)
         */
        $("#info").append("<div id="+j+" class='for-info'></div>");
        $('#load').empty();

        //append each key-value in its particular div
        for(val in json)
            $("#"+j).append('<p>'+val+' --> '+json[val]+'</p>');
        $("#"+j).append("<p><br/></p>");
});
```

So my question is how do I create divisions in the *section* using *div* such that each movie data is in 1 particular *div*? Also I noticed, sometimes the movie at a higher index is retrieved before a lower one. How is this possible when I'm using loops to control this?

Comment: You can retrieve data about a movie with a higher index because it's using an async method, meaning sometimes the latency for retrieving a result may take longer and the results may be returned in a slightly different order (because the code continues, rather than stopping and waiting for the returned value and then continuing).  To avoid this is may be worth grabbing the data to a local array and once that's finished iterate over that array.

Comment: `getJSON()` is _asynchronous_ so you might get your responses in a different order than you sent your requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As WhiteHat rightly says, $.getJSON is asynchronous, can't guarantee one will finish before the other. Also you can see that value of 'j' changes before $.getJSON finish.

If you want to make sure that getJSON run synchronously, you can use [promises](https://www.promisejs.org/).

In jQuery 1.5, Ajax methods return promises. The return value has .done(), .always() and .fail() methods that run when getJSON finish.

```
function processFilms (film, i) {
   if(!i) i = 0;
   if (film && i >= 0 && i < film.length){
      $.getJSON("http://www.omdbapi.com/?t="+film[i]+"&y=&plot=short&r=json")
      .done(
         function (json) {
            console.log("processing "+i+" : "+film[i]);
            $("#info").append("<div id="+i+" class='for-info'></div>");
            for(val in json)
               $("#"+i).append('<p>'+val+' --> '+json[val]+'</p>');
            $("#"+i).append("<p><br/></p>");
            $('#load').empty();
            processFilms(film, i+1);
         }
      );   
   }
}

processFilms(['Fast', 'Nemo']);
```

Note: Other way is use the callback function for you do the recursive call.

Also you can make sure that 'j' doesn't change while that it run $.getJSON. It's asynchronous but 'j' doesn't change.

```
for(var j= 0; j< film.length; j++){
      (function (j_aux) {
         $.getJSON("http://www.omdbapi.com/?t="+film[j]+"&y=&plot=short&r=json", function(json) {
              console.log("processing "+j_aux+" : "+film[j_aux]);
              $("#info").append("<div id="+j_aux+" class='for-info'></div>");
              $('#load').empty();
              for(val in json)
                  $("#"+j_aux).append('<p>'+val+' --> '+json[val]+'</p>');
              $("#"+j_aux).append("<p><br/></p>");
         });
      })(j);
}
```

Comment: The whole problem was that **j** was changing inside **getJSON**. Without promise, I was having to manually set `j = 0` inside **getJSON** and increment it at the end of block. Do you think this way can cause problems later that I cannot predict now?

Comment: If  you set j = 0 inside getJSON then 'j' is 0 in that request. But I understand that you want that 'j' value to be the index in each film request . If you force j = 0 and you increment 'j' at the end of block, then at the beginning of all callbacks j value will be 0. It's indifferent that you increment 'j' at the end of block, in next call, 'j'  back will be assigned to 0 and during all the callback the value won't change. Maybe j must be 0 only in the first request

Answer (score 4):

since `$.getJSON` is asynchronous, can't guarantee one will finish before the other

so, create and assign the `div` *before* `$.getJSON`

```
for(var i= 0; i< film.length; i++){
    $('#load').html("<h2>LOadiNG.....................</h2>");

    for(var j= 0; j< film.length; j++){
        $("#info").append("<div id="+j+" class='for-info'></div>");
        $.getJSON("http://www.omdbapi.com/?t="+film[j]+"&y=&plot=short&r=json", function(json) {
            for(val in json){
                $("#"+j).append('<p>'+val+' --> '+json[val]+'</p>');
            }
            $("#"+j).append("<p><br/></p>");
            $('#load').empty();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem still persists. But I've been able to pinpoint the problem, I think. The logic seems fine but the problem is the loop control variable **j**. Outside the **getJSON** block, **j** works as expected but inside it doesn't. In fact, **j** has the value film.length for some reason. Does asynchronous call have to do with it?

Comment: Problem fixed. Inside the **getJSON** function used `if(j == film.length)      j = 0;` and the end of the block with `j++`. Seems to work

Answer (score 0):

You could use css to give your for-info class a border and margin on the bottom, like this:

(Note: I used the :not(:last-child) selector to not apply the divider to the last div.)

```css
.for-info:not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.for-info {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #c3c3c3;
}
```

```html
<div id='movie1' class='for-info'>Some content...</div>
<div id='movie2' class='for-info'>Some content...</div>
<div id='movie2' class='for-info'>Some content...</div>
```

Comment: this is something I'm already doing. I get the division but the results are very random